# Home page redirect after login/signup not working

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, onclick

I am trying to direct the user to the home page after clicking on the sign up/log in button. But the homepage URL shows 'This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405'

Here is the code I used
`<form action="homepage.html" method="post">`
I also tried                     `<div><button onclick="location.href='homepage.html'">Create Account</button></div>`

I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I should have used get instead of post, so its now         `<form action="homepage.html" method="get">`